# How to shift null values to the front of an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, null

Right now, I am coding a sort of mini game, similar to Candy Crush. I'm having some issues getting my column to fall properly. Basically, I need the ArrayList to sort all of the null values to the top, without altering the order of the rest of the values. While I can't post my exact code (places with ""'s are where I have put in pseudo code) due to class requirements, I basically have set up:

```
{
     ArrayList<"Type"> x = new ArrayList<"type">();
     ArrayList<"Object Location"> y = new ArrayList<"Object Location">();
     int z = 0;
      for(int i=0; i<"ArrayListLength"; i++){
          if ("value at point i" ==null){
              z++;
          }
          else {
              x.add("location on grid");
              y.add(new "Object Location"(i, "located column", "Object At"(i,"located column")));
          }
      }
      for (int i=0; i<z; i++){
          "Location i on column"=null;
      }
      for (int i=z; i<"Array List Length"; i++){
          "Location i on column" = y.get(i-z);
      }
       return y;      
}
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, and it's extremely frustrating. Any tips?

Comment: *Is* there anything wrong with your code? What output do you expect for what input? What *actual* output do you get? Add an example.

Comment: It's hard to answer based on your pseudo code, but one thing I don't see in your pseudo code is a check that the added list member is not null.

Comment: instead of doing all the sorting manually you should use Collections.sort with a custom comparator that checks for null.

Comment: Or just count and remove all the null values, and then insert an equal number of nulls at the beginning. Also, do you actually want to sort the existing array, or create a new array in sorted order (as seems to be the case in your code)?

Comment: Lutz, When it's run on the GUI, the list doesn't shift the null values up to the top (essentially making the objects fall like gravity), they stay in the same position. Also, I want to apologize - I am completely new to this website. I would post the whole code, but it violates conduct and I don't want to be removed from my university :/

Answer (score 2):

you have to give a custom comparator to the Collections.sort method otherwise you will get a NPE

```
   List<String> languages = new ArrayList<>();
    languages.add(null);
    languages.add("java");
    languages.add(null);
    languages.add("c");
    languages.add("fortran");
    languages.add(null);
    Collections.sort(languages, new Comparator<String>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if (o1 == null && o2 == null) {
                return -0;
            }
            if (o1 == null) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (o2 == null) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });

    System.out.println(languages);
```

Comment: With `return o1.compareTo(o2);`, this will also sort non-null elements, right? As I understand the question, except for repositioning the null values, the remaining order should be unchanged.

Comment: @tobias_k indeed. Should be "return 0;" at the end.

Comment: Hi @tobias_k thanks, you r right I maybe missread the question... thanks for the comment! :)

Comment: Hi @911DidBush thanks, you r right I maybe missread the question... thanks for the comment! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a copy of the original list with `null` elements in the front, just iterate the original list and use either `add(x)` to append or `add(0, x)` to insert at the front.

```
List<String> elements = Arrays.asList("foo", null, "bar", "blub", null, null);

List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String x : elements) {
    if (x == null) {
        result.add(0, x);
    } else {
        result.add(x);
    }
}
// now, result is [null, null, null, foo, bar, blub]
// and elements is still [foo, null, bar, blub, null, null]
```

If you want to sort the list *in-place*, just use `Collections.sort` with a custom `Comparator`, checking whether the element is `!= null`. (`false < true`, so `null` values are sorted first.)

```
Collections.sort(elements, Comparator.comparing(x -> x != null));
// now, elements is [null, null, null, foo, bar, blub], too
```

Answer (score 0):

If the remaining Order would be unchanged, then I guess the use of two lists here will make sense, check all the elements that are not null and put it in another list, and then just iterate over the old list(which now only have null values) and start adding the elements from the the list you made earlier. This way you would have a new list with `Null` values at the front and the rest in an unchanged order.